# Trouble Accessing Solidity on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

When I do Ctrl+Shift+P on VSCode, I am unable to see Solidity as an option. If unfamiliar with Solidity, it is a language for writing smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain.

I tried typing

> % brew tap ethereum/ethereum

followed by

> % brew install solidity

on the terminal line (Mac) as described on many internet resources, but an error comes up which keeps suggesting I try "brew install --cask cmake", which I have done and has been successful.

Is there anything I can do to access Solidity in VSCode? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must install solidity as an extension.

You do that :

- By pressing <kbd>Ctrl/cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>
- And then writing `solidity` into the search bar.
- After that, you click on the Install button.